# Polymer and npm, update to latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer

I think this is more an **npm** than a Polymer question.
I have a quite large Polymer project, which is now up to version 1.3.0 according to bower.json inside the Polymer folder.

I have been "offline" from this project for about 2 months and now I realized that the Polymer framework is 1.6.0

How can I update to Polymer 1.6.0 using npm?
How can I update all existing components already installed in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is update your `package.json` to contain the latest Polymer version, like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "polymer": "~1.6.0"
}
```

Then, run `npm update --save` (see the [documentation here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)) which will find the latest version compatible with `~1.6.0` (e.g. `1.6.1`) and save it in your dependencies.

If you're not sure what the latest version is, you can "cheat" and set the dependency to `"*"` in your `package.json`, then run `npm update --save`. This will automatically find the latest version and save it in your `package.json`.

You might also find `npm outdated` useful - it will identify outdated dependencies in your `package.json` for you to upgrade.

Comment: Great, so npm update has to be execute only after I manually update my package.json file? Otherwise I just put a * and run update and I will always have the latest?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to manually update your `package.json` and set them to `"*"`, otherwise `npm` will only upgrade to the latest patch version in most cases.